# Old science fiction movie where captured guy grows big from camera flashes

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely recall watching an old movie about a crazy guy who gets caught (can't remember what he did wrong - maybe killed someone's dog) and when some reporters start taking photos of him he grows into a giant. The army is then called in to attack him.

Did I imagine this as I have been searching the internet for a bit and haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Your title implies the camera flashes *caused* him to grow big, is that right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I think he is also behind bars.

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar to me as well, but I've had no luck finding it. Must be something pretty obscure.

Comment: Was this an animation?

Comment: It sounds a bit like *The Amazing Colossal Man*, except that the camera flashes don't cause him to grow - he's growing due to radiation.  But the military does attack him.

Comment: If it's animated, it might be Ante Zaninovic's *HOMO AUGENS.* Unfortunately it doesn't look like it's available online anywhere. "A man who undergoes an agonizing metamorphosis into a growing, bestial cannibal. He reaches colossal size, collapses outside the walls of a city and the populace streams outside to butcher him..."